# Convert numerical based date to alphabetical based in Python

Tags: python, date

I have the following date

```
from datetime import datetime
test = datetime(2015,9,8)
```

Which looks like this:

```
In [18]: type(test)
Out[18]: datetime.datetime

In [19]: print test
2015-09-08 00:00:00
```

What I want to do is to convert

```
2015-09-08
```

into

```
Sept8
```

Basically pick the first four letter of each month and append it to the date.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does it have to be four letters? The standard is three. Do you want a localized name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work and uses the localization of the system:

```
test.strftime("%B")[:4] + str(test.day)
```